# Preview image stored on ftp server in a web app using myfaces

Tags: java, image, web-applications, ftp, myfaces

Sorry if the question seems of a newbie , I have a spring / (js/ myfaces) application I want to preview and image that I stored on FtpServer , what I want is to preview those images using

```
    <tr:image source="/url_to_my_image" shortDesc="help" />
```

Probleme is that I sotred images on an ftp server, in this case there is no access to an external reference directaly

I tried to use `<a4j:mediaOutput` from

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j" %>
```

It gave me an exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
org.ajax4jsf.resource.LookAheadObjectInputStream
```

Ps: I cannot migrate please anyone has an idea about that